# Joomla site translation issue _JSHOP_REVIEWS_BASED_ON

Tags: joomla-3.x, translation

I try to translate the site.
Default language is english and installed german package from backend.
When i set German langauge there are some issue like "_JSHOP_REVIEWS_BASED_ON" displays and not "based on 0 reviews".

I know i have to transalte custom modules,text from map: language/de_DE but i didnt find this and it seems to be a default text that should be in the german joomla language pack.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

This is not a variable from Joomla Core Language pack. This is extension based variable and it belongs most probably to [JoomShopping](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/joomshopping). You can add global translation using [Language Override](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla) or find proper translation for your extension [here](https://www.webdesigner-profi.de/joomla-webdesign/shop/addons.html) if it exists of course.

Comment: Its not JoomShopping and Override didnt work.
Override founds the contact and i changed the value(text),but it didnt affect on front-end.(but thanks for help.)

Comment: You can always load entire components/language directory into for Example NetBeans and search it for this string. That's way you will find to what extension this constant belongs. This is not Joomla Core for 100%.